# d3js bar chart: panning and zooming to specific values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, bar-chart

I want to pan and zoom to a specific area of this bar chart using values from x axis (note, I still want to be able to zoom out/in and pan, so I can't just recreate the chart with the sliced data)

Here's my bar (waterfall) chart:

```
const data = Array.from({ length: 20 }, (_, i) => ({
    letter: i + 1,
    frequency: Math.random()
}));

// Specify the chart’s dimensions.
const width = 928;
const height = 500;
const marginTop = 20;
const marginRight = 0;
const marginBottom = 30;
const marginLeft = 40;

// Create the horizontal scale and its axis generator.
const x = d3.scaleBand()
.domain(data.map(d => d.letter))
.range([marginLeft, width - marginRight])
.padding(.1);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0);

// Create the vertical scale.
const y = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.frequency)]).nice()
.range([height - marginBottom, marginTop]);

// Create the SVG container and call the zoom behavior.
const svg = d3.select(`body`).append('svg')
.attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto;")
.call(zoom);

// Append the bars.
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "bars")
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .join("rect")
    .attr("x", d => x(d.letter))
    .attr("y", (d, i) => {
    if (i === 0) {
        return y(d.frequency); // Start the first bar at the baseline.
    } else {
        const previousY = y(data[i - 1].frequency); // Get the previous bar's y-position.
        const currentY = y(d.frequency); // Get the current bar's y-position.
        return previousY < currentY ? previousY : currentY; // Choose the lower of the two.
    }
})
    .attr("height", (d, i) => {
    if (i === 0) {
        return y(0) - y(d.frequency);
    } else {
        const previousY = y(data[i - 1].frequency); // Get the previous bar's y-position.
        const currentY = y(d.frequency); // Get the current bar's y-position.
        return Math.abs(currentY - previousY); // Calculate the height difference.
    }
})
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("class", (d, i) => {
    if (i === 0) {
        return "up"; // No class for the first bar.
    } else {
        const previousY = y(data[i - 1].frequency); // Get the previous bar's y-position.
        const currentY = y(d.frequency); // Get the current bar's y-position.
        return previousY < currentY ? "down" : "up"; // Add "up" or "down" class.
    }
});

// Append the axes.
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x-axis")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - marginBottom})`)
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y-axis")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${marginLeft},0)`)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove());

function zoom(svg) {
    const extent = [[marginLeft, marginTop], [width - marginRight, height - marginTop]];

    svg.call(d3.zoom()
             .scaleExtent([1, 5])
             .translateExtent(extent)
             .extent(extent)
             .on("zoom", zoomed));

    function zoomed(event) {
        x.range([marginLeft, width - marginRight].map(d => event.transform.applyX(d)));
        svg.selectAll(".bars rect").attr("x", d => x(d.letter)).attr("width", x.bandwidth());
        svg.selectAll(".x-axis").call(xAxis);
    }
}
```

Here's a JSBIN of this: https://jsbin.com/gubuwogobe/edit?js,output

I think the best way to do this is to create a `zoomPanTo()` function that takes two parameters:

1. Start value of the x axis
2. End value of the x axis

Here's what I've tried:

```
function zoomPanTo(startX, endX) {
    const newDomain = [startX, endX];
    
    svg.transition().duration(750)
        .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.scale(width / (newDomain[1] - newDomain[0]))
            .translate(-newDomain[0], 0));
}

zoomPanTo('5', '10');
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, and I'm a bit stumped how I can get this working.